# rake spec:models VS rspec spec/models which is recommended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec, rake

We figured out both commands

```
rake spec:models
```

and

```
rspec spec/models
```

behave slightly differently in the way that the rake task cleans up the database first. Our tests relies on some initial data (from `db/seeds.rb`) so `rake spec:models` fails.

In the meantime I'm pretty sure one of these commands will get deprecated on day or another.

Which one should we trust?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither will be deprecated, but you are correct that you're on your own to run `rake db:test:prepare` before you run `rspec spec/models`. Assuming you have a standard default configuration, you should only have to do that once.

The drawback of `rake spec:models` is that it loads the Rails environment twice: once in development mode, and once in test mode.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, so we will stick to `rspec spec/models` as it lets us more control over the database seed.